# What are effective techniques for reducing SSL "handshake" time on page load?

Tags: performance, ssl, pagespeed

After running page load time tests on my site via WebPagetest.com and Pingdom.com, I noticed our SSL negotiation time is quite high and hindering the page load.

Is this a result of a poor quality SSL?  Or are there techniques I could use to reduce the SSL handshake time?

Comment: How high is quite high?

Comment: Anywhere from 1-2 secs per handshake.

Comment: Handshake is heavy by design. This doesn't look awfully long... What is the traffic, do you use load balancer?

Comment: Traffic is low, no load balancers currently.  1-2 seconds is normal?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a handshake per page load. There is a handshake per SSL session, which outlive HTTP connections, which themselves outlive single page loads, via keepalive.

Probably you are seeing page load times, not SSL handshake times.

Or else you don't have HTTP keepalive enabled, or you've configured excessively short SSL session timeouts. HTTP keepalive should be at least 15 seconds, and SSL session timeouts should be ten minutes at least.